# Update Non bundled IBM java in websphere application server on Linux

Tags: java, websphere, application-server

Our WAS85 JVM is using non bundled IBM java, at /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java_1.8_64/

updating the WAS fixpack is only updating bundled java(/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/)

how do I update the non bundled java?

I got the latest IBM SDK at https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/java-sdk-downloads-version-80

using the console installation,

Can I just provide the above path during the java install to to update the java SDK?

### ==================
Choose Install Folder

Where would you like to install?

Default Install Folder: /tmp/ibm-java-i386-80

ENTER AN ABSOLUTE PATH, OR PRESS  TO ACCEPT THE DEFAULT
:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java_1.8_64/

Answer (score 0):

Since WebSphere 8.5.5.14, Java 8 is the default SDK included in the product. There is no longer separate SDK needed, and it is automatically updated when you update WebSphere.

Please install latest fixpack from here https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6473497
And your SDK 1.8 will be updated to the latest release.